# Disable audio and popup in MS Teams desktop for everything except calls and meeting notifications

Tags: windows-11, desktop, microsoft-teams

**Goal**:  minimize intrusive notifications. I want all notifications to be only within Teams and not audible except for Calls and Meeting notifications. I want all other notifications to be only within Teams program.

MS Teams is showing a Popup and an audible notification on any chat post within a Team.  This is very distracting and disrupting my "flow".

This is Teams on the desktop, v 1.6.00.35961

I'm also going to try "New Teams" (whatever that is :)